# why imacros javascript #EANF# not working

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

i am extracting data from a website. it is running thru multiple loops and data not found for some loop urls. i am capturing iimextract() to handle #EANF# but it never goes to this even though extracted data is saving in output file = #EANF#

What am i doing wrong.

```
var macro1;
macro1  =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries;1/AX" + jsLF; 


var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=hiprsites.txt" + jsLF;


var rr1;

iimplay(macro1);

for(var i=17;i<=37;i++)
{
iimDisplay(i);
iimSet("i", i);
var rr1=iimPlay(macro);
rr1=iimGetExtract();

if (rr1=="#EANF#")

{
iimDisplay("not found");
}
iimSet("i",i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you save extracted data to file Extract parameter become blank - that is what you get with your iimGetExtract();
you need to remove SAVES from macro to get real extracted data